# How do I pass vertices[] to a constructor?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using C++ and OpenGL. I'm trying to do some mock design of a model loader and renderer.

Here is where I'm getting stuck:

I have been drawing to the screen with my renderer class and window class, no problems there.
I'm using a generic model class that until now was hard coded to take vertices[108] and colors[108] and draw a cube. This works and I could instance hundreds of cubes just fine. However, I was always creating the model(s) by using vertices[108] and colors[108].

Now I want to ditch the [108] and just pass vertices and colors of any sizes into the model constructor.

Right now it looks like in pseudo code:

```
//this is in main.cpp
GLfloat vertices[108] = {
//vertices here
};
GLfloat colors[108] = {
//colors
};
mynamespace::Model::cube(vertices,colors);
```

That is how I a have been using this and within the model class:

```
`//this is in model class declaration
GLfloat vertices_[108];
GLfloat colors_[108];
//then in the constructor definition
Model::Model(vertices,colors) {
//loop through, i<108, and assign vertices,colors to vertices_,colors_
}
`
```

This has worked fine for learning purposes. I now would like to start creating various size vertices[] and sending them along to the Model constructor. (The number of vertices and colors will match - will check that). But I am having a hard time removing that hard coded index, e.g. vertices[108], and just sending along vertices[unknown until it arrives].

I thought, worst case,  I could send a vertices[] through and then in the constructor defn, receive the vertices, check the sizeof() and divide by 4 and assign values by loop if nothing else would work. However, when I send any size vertices[] through and print out the sizeof() to check it, I always get 4 bytes...and nothing draws of course.

To be clear, I'm not getting errors in my code and I don't have a particular code I want to debug so I'm not pasting an existing code sample to solve anything. This is meant to be here is what I'm trying to do, what are some recommendations from experienced folks.

What is a good practice for doing this type of thing?

After this, I want to start loading mesh from files but first I want to understand how I am supposed to pass along various amounts of vertices and make a model so I can send models to the renderer.

Comment: You can either rely on outside storage of vertices and just pass the pointer and the size (number of vertices) to the constructor of model class. You can also use these arguments to make a "private" copy inside the model class. For this, read about [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). To pull out the "raw data" from a `std::vector` it provides a method `std::vector::data()`.

Comment: This worked - thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 4 bytes because when u pass the array to a function, the array degenerate into a Type * pointer. So u didn't get the length of array, instead u got the size of the pointer.

Since u have said u are new to both.

A simple way to work around is to def your fun

```
fun(Type array,int n)
```

When u invoke, you call like this:

```
fun(array,sizeof(array))
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Oh that is why I get 4 bytes, I didn't realize. This worked to send the array into the constructor. I had some trouble with copying it into the model object though because of initializing an unknown array size in the model class. But I could send it in and do things with it but trying to copy to the vertices of the class was giving me trouble.  Scheff reply above to use std::vector inside the class to copy it works though if I pass it like you have show here, then copy to the vector in the class. Thanks!

Comment: @Necromon Np. Actually there are many ways to bypass. One general way is to just pass a struct with whatever value you want to store which quite similar to the concept Interface Blocks in glsl or a general wrapper class. This is very useful when u targeted at specific subject instead of language in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::vector` (you'll need to include `<vector>` first).

```
//this is in model class declaration
std::vector<GLfloat> vertices_;
std::vector<GLfloat> colors_;
//then in the constructor definition
Model::Model(const std::vector<GLfloat> &vertices, const std::vector<GLfloat> &colors) {
    vertices_ = vertices;
    colors_ = colors;
}
```

and then:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> vertices = {
//vertices here
};
std::vector<GLfloat> colors = {
//colors
};

mynamespace::Model cube(vertices,colors);
```

Of course, you can remove all the `std::`s if you have `using std::vector;` or `using namespace std;`

Comment: @Varaquilex I thought about omitting `move`. But if I omitted it someone other than you would be writing a comment about how I should use move semantics. `std::move` calls can be omitted here if you're afraid of them - it won't break anything but the code may run slightly slower. (There's a copy already anyway)

Comment: haha, you're right, otherwise someone would point out you missed move semantics. You can't satisfy all the programmers I guess.

Comment: Ack, there is no reason to tell a beginner to use move semantics here. Just pass by const ref and initialize; it's one copy either way. Even for non-beginners, many hold the view that value & move initialization should not be used unless a need has been shown.

Comment: Sure... cue "you should be using initializer lists" and "you shouldn't be telling beginners to use const" in 5... 4... 3...